# Crear una determinada carpeta con python para guardar recortes de opencv

Tags: python, opencv

tengo el siguiente codigo en python para hacer el reconocimiento y recortes de  contornos, el codigo funciona correctamente, pero necesito que me genere en una determinada direccion  para los archivos recortados y al mismo tiempo necesito crear una carpeta nueva cada vez que se ejecuta el codigo, por ejemplo digamos que tengo este codigo en una carpeta "Deteccion de Objetos" dentro de dicha carpeta quiero crear una carpeta con el nombre "1" cuando se ejecute por primera vez el codigo, luego quiero que los recortes de cada forma encontrada en la imagen se guarden ahi, en caso de que se vuelva a ejecutar el codigo quiero que se cree una carpeta con el nombre "2" y que ahi se guarden los nuevos recortes de la segunda consulta y asi sucesivamente cada vez que se ejecute el codigo.

```
import cv2
import os
path = 'C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/recortes'
image = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/imagenes/Nuevacarpeta/employees-schema.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove dotted lines
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 5000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Fill contours
close_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, close_kernel, iterations=6)
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 15000:
        cv2.drawContours(close, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Smooth contours
close = 255 - close
open_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20,20))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, open_kernel, iterations=3)

# Busca los contornos y dibuja los resultados
ROI_number = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
    #aqui se realiza el recorte de cada entidad
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number)), ROI)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),2)
    ROI_number += 1


print("Cantidad de contornos ", len(cnts))
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa algo distinta (y más compleja sin dudas), es persistir el dato del número de ejecución, esto eventualmente puede ser útil, cuando efectivamente quieres tener una relación univoca entre el # de ejecución y la carpeta:

```
import pickle
import os

class ExecucionPath():

  def __init__(self, basepath = ""):

    self._num = 0
    try:
      with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        self._num = pickle.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
      pass

    self._num = self._num + 1
    with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(self._num, f)

    self._path = os.path.join(basepath, str(self._num).zfill(3))

  def path(self):
    return(self._path)

e = ExecucionPath()
print(e.path())
```

En este caso, la clase `ExecucionPath()` se apoya en el módulo [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) que es la forma más tradicional de "persistir" un dato en python.  En este caso, cada vez que instancies un objeto, mediante `e = ExecucionPath()` se salvará el contador de ejecuciones y el metodo `path()` te retornará el path que le corresponde a la ejecución.

Nota: Si no tienes la necesidad de llevar el control efectivo del número de ejecuciones y sus respectivas carpetas, sin duda la solución de @abulafia es la más óptima.

Answer (score 1):

Pues sería tan sencillo como hacer un listado de las carpetas que tienes dentro de tu carpeta "raiz", odernarlas numéricamente y sumar 1 a la última, para obtener el nombre de la siguiente.

Por cierto yo no las llamaría "1", "2", ... sino "0001", "0002", etc para que cuando las ordenes alfabéticamente te salgan bien (de lo contrario, tras la carpeta "1" alfabéticamente irá la "11" y no la "2").

Por ejemplo puedes tener una función como esta para crear la siguiente carpeta:

```
import os

def crear_siguiente_carpeta(raiz):
    existentes = os.listdir(raiz)

    # Quedarse solo con las que tienen nombre numerico
    existentes = [ int(n) for n in existentes if n.isnumeric() ]

    # Averiguar el numero de la última
    if existentes:
        ultima = max(existentes)
    else:
       ultima = 0

    # Crear nombre para la nueva
    nueva = "{:04}".format(ultima + 1)

    # Crear esa carpeta
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(raiz, nueva))

    # Y retornar su nombre
    return nueva
```

Si llamas a esta función pasándole el nombre de una carpeta (que debe existir previamente), creará en ella una llamada "0001" la primera vez que la ejecutes, y luego "0002", y así sucesivamente. Te retorna el nombre de la carpeta creada, por si la quieres imprimir o usar para otra cosa.